# Get records which are not in tables when passed in In clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, union

I am sure that the title of the question need to get change , but not sure what to put from my end .

I am passing In clause in two Tables want to get the records which are not in both the tables .

Table A contains ID 1,2
Table B contains ID 3,4

I am passing in my In clause (1,2,3,4,5,6)

I am looking for Something

```
1 TableA
2 TableA
3 TableB
4 TableB
5 Not Found
6 Not Found
```

I am using union all to get items from Table A and Table B not sure how to get the not found records in both the table ?

Comment: By your sample which is the result you expected? (5,6)? (1,2)? ...?

Comment: Neither are we unless you provide some details. There is no chance anybody can do much other than pseudocode without any actual details. You might take a look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I want all the records passed in In Clause .. and Which table they belongs to and No found if not present in any table

Comment: What if they are in both tables? And without any details we can't offer much other than vague examples that may or may not be close to what you want.

Comment: @SeanLange I will post few more details , Thanks

Comment: How are these being "passed"? Is this a stored procedure? Are you passing in delimited strings? Table-valued parameters? XML? Does the data already exist in a table?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method.  It uses `exists` to check whether the tables contain the `id`:

```
select id,
       (case when inA = 1 and inB = 1 then 'Both'
             when inA = 1 then 'TableA'
             when inB = 1 then 'TableB'
             else 'Not Found'
        end) as status
from (select id,
             (case when exists (select 1 from tableA a where a.id = ids.id then 1 else 0 end) as inA,
             (case when exists (select 1 from tableB b where b.id = ids.id then 1 else 0 end) as inB
      from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) as ids(id)
     ) i;
```

Of course, you can add `where inA = 0 or inB = 0` if you don't want the `'Both'` rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Col1 INT)
INSERT  @TableA VALUES (1), (2),(5)

DECLARE @TableB TABLE (Col2 INT)
INSERT  @TableB VALUES (3), (4),(5)

-- Query
SELECT t.Col3,
    CONCAT(xa.ExistsInA, ',', xb.ExistsInB) AS SourceTables
    --STUFF(CONCAT(',' + xa.ExistsInA, ',' + xb.ExistsInB), 1, 1, '') AS SourceTables
FROM (VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6)
) AS t(Col3)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  'TableA'
    WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TableA a WHERE a.Col1 = t.Col3)
) xa (ExistsInA)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  'TableB'
    WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TableB b WHERE b.Col2 = t.Col3)
) xb (ExistsInB)
```